Excel crashes with Access Violation in VBE7.DLL after WorkbookOpen event - how to diagnose?
We are working on a optimization of process built in Excel and experiencing a recurring issue with Excel crashing after loading a specific file that contains many worksheets and extensive VBA code. The crash occurs after the WorkbookOpen event has been processed. The Excel file occasionally crashes without any error message when reloaded, even after add-ins have been disabled.
I analyzed the crash dumps using Windbg, and the consistent error across all dumps is an Access Violation (c0000005) in the VBE7.DLL module, specifically in the CEcTypeComp::LookupMember function. This suggests a possible pointer issue or corruption within the VBA environment.
Summed up:
I have tried disabling all Excel add-ins, but the crash still occurs. I also reviewed the VBA code and ensured that no obvious errors were present. The expectation was that either disabling the add-ins or correcting any VBA code issues would prevent the crash, but the problem persists. Additionally, I expected that analyzing the crash dumps with Windbg would help pinpoint the exact cause of the crash, but while it indicates an issue in VBE7.DLL, I'm still unclear on how to proceed to resolve it.
The dumps were created using
procdump -ma -e EXCEL.EXE 

during the crash.
My question is:

How can I further diagnose or narrow down the root cause of this crash?
Are there specific debugging steps or tools within Excel/VBA that can help isolate the problem?
Could this be related to corrupted VBA references or a memory management issue, and how can I address it?

Any insights or suggestions would be greatly appreciated!
Here's one example of the crash dump:
0:000> !analyze -v
*******************************************************************************
*                                                                             *
*                        Exception Analysis                                   *
*                                                                             *
*******************************************************************************

*** WARNING: Check Image - Checksum mismatch - Dump: 0x42c2c9f, File: 0x42cc8a8 - C:\ProgramData\Dbg\sym\EXCEL.EXE\668C50FC42d5000\EXCEL.EXE

KEY_VALUES_STRING: 1

    Key  : AV.Fault
    Value: Read

    Key  : Analysis.CPU.mSec
    Value: 4171

    Key  : Analysis.Elapsed.mSec
    Value: 5286

    Key  : Analysis.IO.Other.Mb
    Value: 0

    Key  : Analysis.IO.Read.Mb
    Value: 1

    Key  : Analysis.IO.Write.Mb
    Value: 0

    Key  : Analysis.Init.CPU.mSec
    Value: 484

    Key  : Analysis.Init.Elapsed.mSec
    Value: 51827

    Key  : Analysis.Memory.CommitPeak.Mb
    Value: 305

    Key  : Failure.Bucket
    Value: INVALID_POINTER_READ_c0000005_EXCEL.EXE!_tailMerge_mso30win32client_dll

    Key  : Failure.Hash
    Value: {3c90ba06-fc72-d981-b986-358ee28f987a}

    Key  : Timeline.OS.Boot.DeltaSec
    Value: 1359697

    Key  : Timeline.Process.Start.DeltaSec
    Value: 27

    Key  : WER.OS.Branch
    Value: vb_release

    Key  : WER.OS.Version
    Value: 10.0.19041.1

    Key  : WER.Process.Version
    Value: 16.0.17726.20160


FILE_IN_CAB:  EXCEL.EXE_240731_112540.dmp

COMMENT:  
*** procdump  -ma -e EXCEL.EXE
*** Unhandled exception: C0000005.ACCESS_VIOLATION

NTGLOBALFLAG:  0

APPLICATION_VERIFIER_FLAGS:  0

CONTEXT:  (.ecxr)
rax=00007ff66cad95a0 rbx=000000606b3867f0 rcx=0000000000792c64
rdx=00007ff66c8f08d8 rsi=0000000000000000 rdi=0000000000000001
rip=00007ff668ff24e1 rsp=000000606b385388 rbp=000000606b3855a0
 r8=00007ff66c8efab0  r9=0000000000000202 r10=000000000000fdff
r11=0000000000002200 r12=0000000000000000 r13=000000606b3856e0
r14=0000020c1255def8 r15=0000000000000001
iopl=0         nv up ei pl nz ac po nc
cs=0033  ss=002b  ds=002b  es=002b  fs=0053  gs=002b             efl=00010214
EXCEL!_tailMerge_mso30win32client_dll+0x18:
00007ff6`68ff24e1 660f7f442420    movdqa  xmmword ptr [rsp+20h],xmm0 ss:00000060`6b3853a8=0000000000000000000000606b3856e0
Resetting default scope

EXCEPTION_RECORD:  (.exr -1)
ExceptionAddress: 00007ff668ff24e1 (EXCEL!_tailMerge_mso30win32client_dll+0x0000000000000018)
   ExceptionCode: c0000005 (Access violation)
  ExceptionFlags: 00000000
NumberParameters: 2
   Parameter[0]: 0000000000000000
   Parameter[1]: ffffffffffffffff
Attempt to read from address ffffffffffffffff

PROCESS_NAME:  EXCEL.EXE

READ_ADDRESS:  ffffffffffffffff 

ERROR_CODE: (NTSTATUS) 0xc0000005 - Die Anweisung in 0x%p verwies auf Arbeitsspeicher bei 0x%p. Der Vorgang %s konnte im Arbeitsspeicher nicht durchgef hrt werden.

EXCEPTION_CODE_STR:  c0000005

EXCEPTION_PARAMETER1:  0000000000000000

EXCEPTION_PARAMETER2:  ffffffffffffffff

STACK_TEXT:  
00000060`6b385388 00007ff6`69ef4c51     : 00000000`00792c64 00007ff6`6c8f08d8 00007ff6`6c8efab0 00000000`00000202 : EXCEL!_tailMerge_mso30win32client_dll+0x18
00000060`6b3853f8 00007ff6`6b21f1d7     : 00007ffa`bd46f6f0 00000060`6b385638 0000020c`5d9d33e0 00000000`00000001 : EXCEL!XlMsoRecoveryMockable::DisableRecoveryAutoLoad+0x31
00000060`6b385428 0000020c`03aa9490     : 00000060`6b3867f0 00000060`00000407 00007ffa`bd413fc0 00000000`00002196 : EXCEL!ProcessNonRecoveryBootCases+0xaa
00000060`6b385468 00000060`6b3867f0     : 00000060`00000407 00007ffa`bd413fc0 00000000`00002196 0000020c`15158e48 : 0x0000020c`03aa9490
00000060`6b385470 00000060`00000407     : 00007ffa`bd413fc0 00000000`00002196 0000020c`15158e48 00000000`05f169d0 : 0x00000060`6b3867f0
00000060`6b385478 00007ffa`bd413fc0     : 00000000`00002196 0000020c`15158e48 00000000`05f169d0 00000000`00000001 : 0x00000060`00000407
00000060`6b385480 864a519a`bd415076     : 0000020c`1515a4c8 00000001`00000000 00000008`00000000 0000020c`00000001 : VBE7!UIAPP::CommitAll+0x3c
00000060`6b3854c0 0000020c`1515a4c8     : 00000001`00000000 00000008`00000000 0000020c`00000001 0000020c`0f569090 : 0x864a519a`bd415076
00000060`6b3854c8 00000001`00000000     : 00000008`00000000 0000020c`00000001 0000020c`0f569090 00007ffa`bd49ab36 : 0x0000020c`1515a4c8
00000060`6b3854d0 00000008`00000000     : 0000020c`00000001 0000020c`0f569090 00007ffa`bd49ab36 00000060`6b385530 : 0x00000001`00000000
00000060`6b3854d8 0000020c`00000001     : 0000020c`0f569090 00007ffa`bd49ab36 00000060`6b385530 00007ffa`bd46fd53 : 0x00000008`00000000
00000060`6b3854e0 0000020c`0f569090     : 00007ffa`bd49ab36 00000060`6b385530 00007ffa`bd46fd53 0000020c`5fe6ce70 : 0x0000020c`00000001
00000060`6b3854e8 00007ffa`bd49ab36     : 00000060`6b385530 00007ffa`bd46fd53 0000020c`5fe6ce70 0000020c`00000001 : 0x0000020c`0f569090
00000060`6b3854f0 00007ffa`bd4061ae     : 00000060`6b385638 0000020c`15157c48 0000020c`1515a830 00007ffa`00000001 : VBE7!BASIC_TYPEROOT::GetNamMgr+0x36
00000060`6b385530 00007ffa`bd46fb6f     : 00000060`6b385638 0000020c`5d99c120 00000060`00000003 00007ffa`bd406190 : VBE7!EPIBIND::`scalar deleting destructor'+0xe
00000060`6b385560 00007ffa`bd470da7     : 0000020c`5d99c168 0000020c`03aa9490 00000000`00000001 00000000`0010c548 : VBE7!EPIBIND::CopyContextFrom+0xaf
00000060`6b3855b0 00007ffa`bd4730d1     : 0000020c`5d99c168 0000020c`03aa9490 00000000`00000001 00000000`0010c548 : VBE7!CEcTypeComp::LookupMemberWithBases+0x127
00000060`6b385690 00007ffa`bd471db8     : 0000020c`5f9eff98 0000020c`03aa9490 0000020c`00000001 00000060`0010c548 : VBE7!CEcProjTypeComp::LookupMember+0x7a9
00000060`6b385f20 00007ffa`bd4726c7     : 0000020c`5f9eff98 0000020c`03aa9490 00000000`00000001 00000000`0010c548 : VBE7!CEcProjTypeComp::LookupFromContext+0x14c
00000060`6b3860d0 00007ffa`bd4876eb     : 0000020c`5f9eff98 0000020c`03aa9490 00000060`6b380001 00007ffa`00000002 : VBE7!CEcProjTypeComp::LookupNames+0x49f
00000060`6b386180 00007ffa`bd39208f     : 0000020c`5dddc4d0 00000060`6b3867f0 00000000`00000001 00000060`6b386810 : VBE7!GEN_PROJECT::Bind+0x1ff
00000060`6b3867c0 00007ff6`6964bb99     : 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000001 00000060`6b386b70 00007ff6`6943126c : VBE7!CVbeProcs::BindProcDisp+0x1c3
00000060`6b3868c0 00007ff6`696171d7     : 0000020c`1255def8 00000000`00000000 00000060`6b386a10 0000020c`5c34fcf0 : EXCEL!HrVbpBindProcDisp+0x79
00000060`6b386910 00007ff6`6a9fc647     : 00000060`6b386e88 00007ff6`68ea4bb5 00000000`00000000 00007ffa`00000000 : EXCEL!FFindOBName+0x430
00000060`6b386de0 00007ff6`690e0311     : 0000020c`15024450 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 00007ff6`694a06b2 : EXCEL!HrLoadOBName+0xfb
00000060`6b386e20 00007ff6`690e5439     : 00000000`00000001 00000000`00000000 0000020c`1594c7c0 0000020c`14cae5a0 : EXCEL!HrQueueOB+0xc5
00000060`6b386e80 00007ff6`690ebc25     : 0000020c`15024450 00000060`00000000 00000060`6b386fb0 0000020c`14cae5a0 : EXCEL!HrBookLoadReferences+0x67
00000060`6b386eb0 00007ff6`690d00b8     : 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000001 00000060`6b387470 0000020c`14ea1610 : EXCEL!HrBookLoadComplete+0x645
00000060`6b387310 00007ff6`690c277b     : 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000f88 00000060`00000000 0000020c`15057bb0 : EXCEL!HrFileLoadEx+0xb40c
00000060`6b397b00 00007ff6`69bf62ea     : 00000000`00000000 0000020c`6dff2dd0 00000000`00000000 00000060`00000000 : EXCEL!HrFileLoadWithCoauth+0xdb
00000060`6b397c20 00007ff6`6b21c735     : 00000000`0000103a 00000000`0000103a 0000020c`6dff2dd0 00000000`00000040 : EXCEL!HrFileLoadWithCoauth+0xaa
00000060`6b397ce0 00007ff6`69b0dba5     : 00000000`0000003b 0000020c`00000001 00000000`00000000 0000020c`15056ea0 : EXCEL!HighlightAndScrollToDrp+0x7d5
00000060`6b39c290 00007ff6`68fcf8b5     : 00000000`00000130 0000020c`05c96490 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000001 : EXCEL!FLoadRecoveredFiles+0x8e5
00000060`6b39ce60 00007ff6`690365f4     : 0000020c`6dff394c 00000060`6b39cfa0 0000020c`05c96490 0000020c`00000015 : EXCEL!Excel::XlBoot::SetupDocRecovery+0xb5
00000060`6b39cea0 00007ff6`68f5ab8e     : 00000000`00000130 00000000`00000003 00000000`00000130 00000000`00000130 : EXCEL!FMainInit+0x2b3a
00000060`6b39f300 00007ff6`6907afd8     : 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 00007ff6`6c8efdc8 00000060`6b39f6c0 : EXCEL!FWinInit+0x3ce
00000060`6b39f5c0 00007ff6`68fefab9     : 00000000`00000001 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 : EXCEL!WinMain+0x958
00000060`6b39f8a0 00007ffb`17a47374     : 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 : EXCEL!_imp_load_RmGetList+0x20d
00000060`6b39f8e0 00007ffb`187bcc91     : 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 : kernel32!BaseThreadInitThunk+0x14
00000060`6b39f910 00000000`00000000     : 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 : ntdll!RtlUserThreadStart+0x21


SYMBOL_NAME:  EXCEL!_tailMerge_mso30win32client_dll+18

MODULE_NAME: EXCEL

IMAGE_NAME:  EXCEL.EXE

STACK_COMMAND:  dt ntdll!LdrpLastDllInitializer BaseDllName ; dt ntdll!LdrpFailureData ; ~0s; .ecxr ; kb

FAILURE_BUCKET_ID:  INVALID_POINTER_READ_c0000005_EXCEL.EXE!_tailMerge_mso30win32client_dll

OS_VERSION:  10.0.19041.1

BUILDLAB_STR:  vb_release

OSPLATFORM_TYPE:  x64

OSNAME:  Windows 10

IMAGE_VERSION:  16.0.17726.20160

FAILURE_ID_HASH:  {3c90ba06-fc72-d981-b986-358ee28f987a}

Followup:     MachineOwner
---------


Kind Regards,
Alexander

Are you able to open the Workbook in a way that blocks the automatic running of Workbook_Open and allows you to edit the VBA code?

From experience, opening a VBA heavy file with Excel can cause crashes if Excel is not already open. Things have been more stable since I started opening a new blank workbook with Excel to make sure everything was initialized properly before opening any file with VBA code.

If you hold down the left shift key while opening the workbook, and keep it depressed until the workbook is fully open, it will prevent the Workbook_Open macro from being executed. You will then be able to examine the references, step through the code, etc.

Do you use Application.ScreenUpdating?

Without the source code and private symbols it won't be easy for you to debug on your own. You might try to open a support case via https://support.microsoft.com/

You have a different version of Excel on your machine than in the crash dump. Do you have an explanation for that? Your symbols might be wrong and thus misleading in the analysis.

What can I say about this: "CEcTypeComp::LookupMember"? You need to check you code for references to properties or methods which can be available or not (look at this topic).
Another reason for Excel to crash can be the endless loop.
Also check and analyze VBA Project references if any non-usual one is in use.
